# Encapsulate jQuery block for reuse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code that I was originally planning to use only once, but now it turns out I have to use it on multiple instances, but I am not very familiar with code encapsulation.

So my question is, first the block:

```
$('.share-checklist-trigger').click(function () {
    $('body').addClass('no-overflow');
    $(document).scrollTop(-1);
    $('.widget-top-drawer.share-checklist-drawer').slideToggle(244, "linear").dimBackground({
        darkness: 0.2
    });
    $('.widget-top-drawer-header').slideToggle(244, "linear").attr('style', 'display: flex;');
    $('.dashboard-main').addClass('top-draw-out');
}).stop();
```

The things that will change from object reference to another is the class after the main class  **`.widget-top-drawer.share-checklist-drawer`** , e.g. - **`.share-checklist-drawer`** will be something else and the main selector e.g. - **`.share-checklist-trigger`** to something else.

How am I able to turn this into a sort of a plugin-type block, so that I can use it on multiple objects, without copy-pasting the same code over and over again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to create an entire plugin for this. Instead you can use the common `.share-checklist-trigger` class to group the required elements. You can then place a `data` attribute on those elements to change the executed logic within the event handler. Try this:

```
<div class="share-checklist-trigger" data-target=".widget-top-drawer.share-checklist-drawer">Foo</div>
<div class="share-checklist-trigger" data-target=".fizz.buzz">Bar</div>
```

```js
$('.share-checklist-trigger').click(function () {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $('body').addClass('no-overflow');
    $(document).scrollTop(-1);
    $(target).slideToggle(244, "linear").dimBackground({
        darkness: 0.2
    });
    $('.widget-top-drawer-header').slideToggle(244, "linear").css('display', 'flex');
    $('.dashboard-main').addClass('top-draw-out');
}).stop();
```

Also note the use of `css()` over setting the `style` directly using `attr()`. this could be further improved by setting the `display: flex` rule in a class in an external stylesheet and using `addClass()` in your JS code.

Comment: Hey @Rory McCrossan , thanks for the quick response. The problem is, I am using this code block like 8 times already. This is why I wanted to encapsulate it.

Comment: The solution above will work for all of those 8 occasions. You just need to change the initial selector to pickup your elements, eg `$('.share-checklist-trigger, .foo, .bar')...`

Comment: Is it possible to change the trigger itself somehow as well? The whole thing inside the main selector?

Comment: No, you can't programmatically change the trigger once the event is bound. You would need to extract the event logic to a function and then bind the event handlers separately.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. All you have to do is put the class `share-checklist-trigger` for every object you want to use this code and define the target in the `data-target` attribute

Comment: Refactor time it is. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.